# GroceryCrud validation custom messages

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, grocery-crud

I have one question.. How to validate fields data with custom error messages? I use codeigniter, and grocery crud with twitter bootstrap theme, and do some field required, for example:

```
$crud->set_rules('first_name', 'NAME', 'required'); OR $crud->required_fields('first_name');
```

Validation work fine, but if validation unsuccessfull - we see just alert with standart message - "An error has occurred on insert\update". How to display custom message that field are required or etc. ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is old topic, but i thing someone can get this error as me just get it.

We can't use CI set_message function for CroceryCrud validation.
Because CroceryCrud use its validation object.

You can edit libraries/Grocery_CRUD.php, find line "protected function form_validation()",

at under this function, you can copy it, rename and edit access modifiler to public :

```
public function get_form_validation(){
        if($this->form_validation === null)
    {
        $this->form_validation = new grocery_CRUD_Form_validation();
        $ci = &get_instance();
        $ci->load->library('form_validation');
        $ci->form_validation = $this->form_validation;
    }
     return $this->form_validation;
}
```

Now, you can call it in your controller :

```
 $crud-> get_form_validation()->set_message('check_city',"invail %s");
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at function `set_message` in `form_validation` library:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#settingerrors

Comment: Don't work with grocery crud. I have tried use standart codeigniter validation library, but validation always true and validation_errors() return empty string...